# The .prop() function isn't changing an element's name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Jquery/javascript code which clones a template element and assigns the clone an iterative ID (so the first clone is called 'eventCard0', the second 'eventCard1' etc.)

This works fine besides `.prop('name', 'eventCard' + number)` which for some reason doesn't change the clone's name attribute in the same manner as it changes the clone's ID. I can't figure out why this is at all

```
var newEventBtn = document.getElementById("newEventButton");

newEventBtn.onclick = function() {
    let number = $('#events .eventInputs').length;
    let cloneParent = "#eventCardTemplate";
    let newClone = $(cloneParent).clone().prop('id', "eventCard" + number).prop('name', "eventCard" + number);
    newClone.appendTo("#events");
}
```

This is the template tag `<li id="eventCardTemplate" name="eventCardTemplate" class="eventInputs">`

And this is the entire HTML:

```
<?php
    session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
            header('Location: index.html');
            exit();
        }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Timeline Creator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timelineCreator.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <li id="eventCardTemplate" name="eventCardTemplate" class="eventInputs">
        <input type="text" name="eventName" class="eventName" maxlength="50" placeholder="Event Name" required>
        <textarea name="eventDesc" class="eventDesc" placeholder="Event Description" required></textarea>
        <p class="label">Start Date</p>
        <input type="date" name="startDate" class="date" required>
        <!-- <label for="startIsEnd">Start date = End Date</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="startIsEnd" class="startIsEnd"> -->
        <p class="label">End Date</p>
        <input type="date" name="endDate" class="date" required>
        <p class="label">Political</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="political" value="political" class="checkboxes">
        <p class="label">Economic</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="economic" value="economic" class="checkboxes">
        <p class="label">Social</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="social" value="social" class="checkboxes">
    </li>
    <a href="home.php"><-- Back</a>
    <form action="createTimeline.php" method="post" id="timelineCreator">
        <input type="text" name="timelineName" id="timelineName" maxlength="50" placeholder="Timeline Name" autofocus required>
        <textarea id="timelineDesc" name="timelineDesc" placeholder="Timeline Description" required></textarea>
        <ul id="events">
        </ul>
        <button type="button" id="newEventButton">+ Add Event</button>
        <input type="submit" id="createTimeline" value="Create Timeline">
    </form>
    <script src="timelineCreator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `.attr`

Comment: Why are you using `.onclick` when you're using jQuery?

Comment: Do not mix native JS with JQuery (`document.getElementById()`, `onclick()`).

Comment: @Barmar using `.attr` worked thank you. Why does `.prop` work for changing the ID but not for changing the name? I'm very new to jQuery so don't know all of its capabilities yet which is why I'm using `.onclick` rather than the jQuery alternative, what should I use instead?

Comment: You should use `$("#newEventButton").click(function ...)`

Comment: The `id` attribute and property are automatically linked to each other because it's a standard property of all elements. But the `name` property is not standard for most element types, so setting the property doesn't set the attribute.

Comment: You generally shouldn't add nonstandard attributes to elements. If you need custom data, use `data-XXX` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Your element does not have the name property, so .prop won't change it.

Look at this link for a list of elements that do have the name property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

In this case you should be using .attr instead of .prop :

```
let newClone = $(cloneParent).clone().attr('id', "eventCard" + number).attr('name', "eventCard" + number);
```